# Symfony 6 request headers get authorization null value

Tags: angular, symfony, request, http-headers

Some help here please. I'm stuck and out of ideas now.
I'm working on an Angular project (frontend) that makes API requests to a Symfony 6 project (backend).
Everything works fine in my local environment but I'm publishing it to a hosting and I'm having problems.

The project on the server is partially working. Some get requests are collecting results. The problems appear on the secured pages.

From the angular frontend I'm trying to create an entity by making a POST call to Symfony. In this call I add in the headers:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: [token string]
```

The response returns a 500 error because the line in the Symfony controller to retrieve the token value gets a null value.
Here the line in the controller:

```
#[Route('/category/create', name: 'app_category_create', methods:['POST'])]
    public function create(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $doctrine, JwtAuth $jwt_auth)
    {
        $token = $request->headers->get('Authorization', null);
...
```

I've got this in the .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And finally this is the index.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

As I mentioned at the beginning, it works correctly in my local. I don't understand what is happening...

Can someone help me figure out why the backend is not receiving the token value, please?

**EDIT**
I've changed some headers in the index.php of the backend and Authorization headers still getting null value.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, x-auth-token");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

I have tried to send the same token using the X-API-KEY header and **it works**. I'm pretty lost. I don't understand what's happening...

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following lines to your .htaccess file should resolve the issue:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Some hosting companies don't allow Authorization request header, and this configuration ensures that the Authorization header is correctly passed to your Symfony application, resolving the CORS issue you've encountered.